# Send request body data when running siege

Tags: performance-tuning

I am trying to use the command line utility Siege to load test a service. The service recieves json in the request body via a POST.

I have a file called example-data.json with the json inside.

I will eventually turn this into a tiny service which creates random json for testing, but this should do for now

I have another file called hit-qa.siege with

http://www.qa-url.com POST < example-data.json

and i try and run

`siege -c10 -d1 -r1 -f ops/perf/hammer-dev.siege`

When I check the logs of the service, it is not recieving anything in the request body. My googles have been fruitless, does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem running **Siege 3.0.1**... and looks like it was caused by a bug ([release notes](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home)).

After upgrading to **Siege 3.0.5** it just started to send the JSON POST contents again.